# Do transistors have direction?

Tags: transistors

On diagrams the transistor have usually a direction - it is assumed that (for bipolar NPN) current goes from base to emitter and it is reflected in symbol:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQkDEM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However when if I look how transistors are actually being built it seems that there is no difference between collector and emitter - both are N regions (for NPN transistors). Is there a difference between them I can't see or is it just a convention to allow reader get the intended direction or current?

(I described bipolar but I'm also interested in FETs)

Comment: "... if I look how transistors are actually being built ..." You aren't seeing how they're built, you're seeing a very simplified model that hides the polarity.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/33303/what-is-the-difference-between-emitter-and-collector-for-bjts

Comment: @τεκ Sorry - search didn't find that one.