# TTL NAND circuit implementation

Tags: ttl, nand

I analyze implementation of TTL NAND circuit and there is multi emitter BJT which works in reverse active mode for some combination of input signals.
In book I use, they said that it works in reverse active mode, but didn't prove that statement. 
We know that when we analyse circuits with BJT's, we assume mode of operation of BJT, solve circuit and then check if our assumption is correct. What equations are used for BJT in revere active mode? How can I prove that it is really in revese active mode?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do some research first...
[BJT in Reverse Active Mode of Operation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29756/bjt-in-reverse-active-mode-of-operation)

The answer to your question:
http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/312/handouts/BJT%20Structure%20and%20Modes%20of%20Operation.pdf

Under "Regions of operation":
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor

Comment: Downvoted because the answer consists of just links without any summary, which is discouraged here because the links (particularly the middle one) may go bad at some time in the future (the other two seem safe).